# Listas encadeadas

Tags: c

Estou tendando criar um programa que conforme eu vou entrando com os valores, ele vai adicionando no inicio da lista encadeada, pelo que eu vi ele ta guardando os valores certinho, mas na hora de printar ele não printa, como se a lista estivesse vazia, procurei o erro e não encontrei mas acho que é relacionado ao ponteiro na função de inserir, alguem pode me mostrar o erro? preciso mesmo aprender isso logo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cel
{
    int valor;
    struct cel * prox;
};

typedef struct cel celula;

int inserir(celula *ini);
void escreve(celula *ini);

void main()
{
    int i,aux;
    celula *inicio;
    inicio = NULL;

    i=0;
    do
    {
        printf("\nLista[%d]:",i+1);
        aux = inserir(&inicio);
        printf("\n%d",aux);
        i++;
    } while (aux == 1);
    escreve(&inicio);
}

int inserir(celula *ini)
{
    int n;
    celula * aux;

    aux = (celula*) malloc(sizeof(celula));
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    aux->valor = n;
    aux->prox = ini;
    ini = aux;
    return 1;
}

void escreve(celula *ini)
{
    int i=1;
    celula * aux;

    aux=ini;
    while(aux->prox != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nlista[%d]=%d",i,aux->valor);
        i++;
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Procure colocar o código identado corretamente. Isso vai facilitar muito a resolução do seu problema.

Comment: então eu não sei mto bem usar o stackoverflow, se puder me explicar como eu coloco o código certinho eu agradeço

Comment: Eu tbm não sou muito experiente, mas a maneira como eu faço é ir em editar e identar na mão mesmo. As vezes vale mais a pena pegar seu código e colocar num editar de texto, identar com espaços (não tabs) e colar aqui.

Comment: é que eu tinha visto que se usasse CTRL+K ele fazia isso, mas só agora que eu vi que tem que selecionar o texto e depois apertar o atalho, agora ficou certinho

Comment: detalhe mais o erro... ocorre quando você faz oque? Oque mostra na mensagem de erro?

Comment: editei ali, mas eu acho que o ponteiro ta apontando pro lugar errado, mas como não sou muito experiente não sei identificar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem várias coisas que precisa de corrigir:

- Para conseguir fazer a inserção tem de passar um ponteiro para o ponteiro do `main` aqui:

  ```
  int inserir(celula **ini);
  ```

  Caso contrário não irá conseguir o ponteiro no `main` quando ele está a `NULL`. Isto até corresponde à chamada que já estava a ser feita (corretamente):

  ```
  aux = inserir(&inicio);
  ```
- Uma vez que a função `escreve` não precisa de alterar a lista pode passar o ponteiro normalmente sem ser o endereço do ponteiro como esta a fazer:

  ```
  escreve(&inicio); //deve ser apenas escreve(inicio);
  ```
- Na função `insere` tem de passar a receber o endereço do ponteiro do `main` e modificar o seu valor tendo em especial atenção quando é `NULL`, que é o valor inicial.
- Na impressão da lista:

  ```
  while(aux->prox != NULL)
  ```

  Deve percorrer até que o ponteiro seja `NULL` e não o `->prox!=NULL`, caso contrário o ultimo elemento não será mostrado.

Aplicando todas estas alterações o código ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cel
{
    int valor;
    struct cel * prox;
};

typedef struct cel celula;

int inserir(celula **ini); //agora **
void escreve(celula *ini);

void main()
{
    int i = 0,aux;
    celula *inicio = NULL;

    do
    {
        printf("\nLista[%d]:",i+1);
        aux = inserir(&inicio);
        printf("\n%d",aux);
        i++;
    } while (aux == 1);
    escreve(inicio); //sem &
}

int inserir(celula **ini)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;

    //só cria se não for 0 para não alocar memoria não utilizada
    celula * aux = (celula*) malloc(sizeof(celula)); 

    aux->valor = n;
    aux->prox = ini == NULL ? NULL : *ini; //liga para o que veio do main ou NULL
    *ini = aux; //agora com * para modificar o ponteiro que veio do main

    return 1;
}

void escreve(celula *ini)
{
    int i=1;
    celula * aux = ini;

    while(aux != NULL) //sem usar o ->prox aqui
    {
        printf("\nlista[%d]=%d",i,aux->valor);
        i++;
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
}
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/8kUKS9)

Optei também por simplificar algumas declarações que tinha como:

```
celula * aux;

aux = (celula*) malloc(sizeof(celula));
```

Para

```
celula * aux = (celula*) malloc(sizeof(celula));
```

Para tornar o código mais curto e mais legível.

Comment: Pode me explicar pra que serve esses operadores?(dois pontos e "?")

Comment: @GuilhermeGarcia Isso é basicamente um operador ternário, um `if` numa só linha, que acaba por ficar mais curto. Um exemplo simples seria `int x = a == 2? 10:20;`. Se `a` for `2`, `x` fica com `10` caso contrário fica com `20`. Na resposta o `aux->prox = ini == NULL ? NULL : *ini;` é interpretado como: `aux->prox` fica com `NULL` se `ini` for `NULL` senão fica com `*ini` que é o valor apontado por `ini`

Comment: Consegui entender, realmente assim fica mais simples de usar

Answer (score 0):

vou tentar ajudar:

Resposta CURTA, segue o codigo corrigido, coloquei /// nas linhas em q eu fiz alguma alteracao:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct cel
    {
        int valor;
        struct cel * prox;
    };

    typedef struct cel celula;

    int inserir(celula **ini);///
    void escreve(celula *ini);

    void main()
    {
        int i,aux;
        celula *inicio;
        inicio = NULL;

        i=0;
        do
        {
            printf("\nLista[%d]:",i+1);
            aux = inserir(&inicio);
            printf("\n%d",aux);
            i++;
        } while (aux == 1);
        escreve(inicio);///
    }

    int inserir(celula **ini)
    {
        int n;
        celula * aux;

        aux = (celula*) malloc(sizeof(celula));
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n == 0)
            return 0;
        aux->valor = n;
        aux->prox = *ini;///
        *ini = aux;///
        return 1;
    }

    void escreve(celula *ini)
    {
        int i=1;
        celula * aux;

        aux=ini;
        while(aux != NULL)///
        {
            printf("\nlista[%d]=%d",i,aux->valor);
            i++;
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
    }
```

Resposta LONGA, vou tentar explicar o problema.

Da uma olhada nas seguintes linhas:

```
aux = inserir(&inicio);
.
.
int inserir(celula *ini)
```

Aqui eu nao sei se vc sabia oq tava fazendo chamando o endereco de um ponteiro e só esqueceu de colocar um asterisco na funcao inserir(), ou se colocou o & na esperanca de dar certo (eu faco isso as vezes...). Contado q o segundo caso é verdadeiro o problema aparece no seu apontamento ja q vc inicia o ponteiro como nulo e na primeira chamada de inserir o seu `inserir(inicio)` é igual a `inserir(NULL)`, e aew a sua atribuicao `ini = aux;` ja nao faz mais sentido.

O proximo problema ta no escreve, esta linha

```
 while(aux->prox != NULL)
```

pergunta se o proximo é nullo, oq faz com q toda vez q vc for printar o primeiro valor inserido nao vai aparecer

Acho q é isso, espero ter ajudado, boa sorte aew